# How do I solve this system of equations $x^2-xy+2y^2=28$, $x^2-3xy-y^2=16$?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

How do I solve this system of equations $x^2-xy+2y^2=28$, $x^2-3xy-y^2=16$?

I started to get $x$ than to put it in equation but it didn't help me.

Comment: Why don't you show us what you tried?

Comment: For reference, WA does obtain answers in radicals for the four roots: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2-xy%2B2y%5E2%3D28+and+x%5E2-3xy-y%5E2%3D16. So this problem should be tractable by hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe that
\begin{align*}
x^2-xy+2y^2+2(x^2-3xy-y^2)&=28+2\cdot 16\\
3x^2-7xy&=60\\
3x-7y&=\frac{60}x\\
y&=\frac17\left(3x-\frac{60}x\right)
\end{align*}

Then
$$x^2-xy+2y^2=28\quad\iff\quad x^2-\frac17\left(3x^2-60\right)+\frac2{49}\left(9x^2-360+\frac{3600}{x^2}\right)=28$$
Last equation can be put in the form
$$Ax^4+Bx^2+C=0$$
and then you can solve by making the sustitution $u=x^2$.

Comment: (+1) for an answer that makes apparent that the solution will have $\pm$ symmetry in $x$.

Answer (score 0):

If you [feed it to Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2-xy%2B2y%5E2%3D28,%20x%5E2-3xy-y%5E2%3D16), you have the intersection of an ellipse with a hyperbola.  There are four points.  Alpha returns approximate values because the exact values (which it will provide) are a mess.  It probably just uses the quadratic formula on one of the equations and substituted into the other, getting a quartic to solve.  There ain't no graceful way.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Steps are problem not solution

Comment: The fact that the exact values it obtains are expressed entirely in terms of square roots makes me wonder if there's really no more better way to proceed. (I agree, though, that any method is not likely to be 'graceful'.) For instance, it looks geometrically plausible that the axes of the ellipse are the asymptotes of the hyperbola.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Put $y=mx$ as $xy\ne0$

divide the relation derived by eliminating $x$

to find the value of $m$

Comment: @Semiclassical, Sorry for the typo

Answer (score 0):

multiplying the first equation by $-1$ and adding to the first we obtain
$$2xy+3y^2=12$$ and from here we get
$$2xy=12-3y^2$$ thus $$x=\frac{12-3y^2}{2y}$$ from here you can eliminate $x$

Answer (score 0):

By elimination (algorithmically by [computing the Gröbner basis using e.g. wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=groebnerbasis%5B%7Bx%5E2%E2%88%92xy%2B2y%5E2-28,+x%5E2%E2%88%923xy%E2%88%92y%5E2-16%7D,%7Bx,y%7D%5D)) these two polynomials can be derived from your input:

$23 y^4 - 208 y^2 + 144, 24 x + 23 y^3 - 172 y$

Their set of zeroes is the same as the set of solutions for your original equations. From the first polynomial you get a closed form solution for all the $y$s, from the second polynomial you get a closed from solution for each corresponding $x$.